# MYSQL Forced pattern match

Tags: mysql, regex, matching

I am having trouble figuring out if its possible to force mysql to consider certain specified strings as identical when choosing results in a select query.

For example i have a column containing the word "trachiotomy", but due to the nature of the language it is very likely that the search query will be "trahiotomy" (notice the c missing).

Is there any way I can force the query to recognize any pattern of letters to another ?
For example to match any instance within words of the "ach" sequence of letters to "ah" also - and vice versa. In essence force it regardless of how it was written.

Another example would be the word Archon - which I would like to match with Arhon as well.
So that if a user input was Archon it would match the database data Arhon and vice versa.

I experimented with soundex a bit and it does match some instances, but it seems that due to the way the algorithm works it cant do it in cases where the desired matched string is in the beginning of the word.

For instance the word "Chorevo" cant match the word "Horevo" unless i can somehow force it to consider that "chor" is equal to "hor" and vice versa in any word.

I am reading into REGEXP to see if it can be matched thus somehow. (something like
REGEXP 'arch', 'arh')

At this point i am using a full text match query, but could change that if that proves to be a problem.

I am not sure I have made this clear but would appreciate any help possible.

Comment: Could a levenshtein algoritm be used? Something like: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552

Comment: I tested levenstein (custom function) but it doesn't seem to be able to cover the issue with these types of words (especially in the case of Chorevo/Horevo which start with diferent letters, even though they are phonetically similar) but I will make another attempt, as I didn't delve too deeply because it seemed to be a bit slow with a large data set.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as phonetic matching.  MySQL implements a relatively primitive version of this in the `soundex(str)` function and `a SOUNDS_LIKE b` clause (which is just shorthand for `soundex(a) = soundex(b)`.  By nature such matching is language-specific, and the MySQL implementation is designed for English words and thus may not work in your situation.

Alternatively you could research/write your own transformation that does what you want and apply it to the data before saving in the database (in a separate column or table).

Comment: Unfortunately the soundex algorithm cant match cases like the one i described very well as the first letter (which is a critical factor of the algorithm) is different.

Comment: Which is why I think you will need to write your own hashing algorithm that does what you need.